# pipe and stdin redirection to cat

Tags: pipe, cat

Why does

```
echo "hello world" | cat
```

works while

```
cat < echo "hello world"
```

does not?  My (incorrect) intuition is that pipe would redirect `stdout` to `cat` as `stdin`.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that a pipe is different from a redirection. From the manual of bash, it seems that you can only redirect a file as input.

Comment: In bash you can do `cat <<< "hello word"`, if interested you can do `man bash` and search for `Here Strings`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We have two similar but different things

- A *pipeline*

  ```
  echo "hello world" | cat   # This is a pipeline
  ```

  The pipe control operators (`|` and `|&`) connect the output of a command to the input of the following one in the pipeline. **So the first example works**, the output of the `echo` command, "Hello word", is connected with the input of the following `cat` command, that assumes the standard input as input file if not else specified. Indeed we can read from `man cat`:

  > cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

  and below the example with the simple invocation of `cat`

  > `cat       Copy standard input to standard output`
- A redirection, or better an attempt of input redirection `<`

  ```
  cat < echo "hello world"   # This is an attempt of redirection
  ```

  In this case `cat` command is taking its input from the standard input that you **redirect** with the operator `<` from the file on the right side of `<`... that is not a file. This is **because it doesn't work**.

  From the redirection section of the `man bash`

  > Redirecting Input
  >      Redirection of input causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for reading on file descriptor  n,  or  the  standard  input
  >      (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified.
- In bash it works for different reasons

  - `cat <(echo "hello world")`   Process Substitution

    > Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.  It takes the form of  `<(list)`  or `>(list)`.   The  process list is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in `/dev/fd`.  The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.  If the `>(list)` form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list.  If the `<(list)` form  is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.
  - `cat <<< $(echo "hello world")` Here Strings

    > The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.  Path-name expansion and word splitting are not performed.  The result is supplied as a single string to the command on its standard input.

**References**

- `man bash` and search for *redirection*, *pipeline*, *Here Strings* and *Process substitution*
- `man cat` just because we use it...

Answer (score 2):

That stream reads from files. `>` is out to a file and `<` is in from a file. Demonstration:

First `echo "HELLO HELLO HELLO" > HELLO.txt` and then `cat < HELLO.txt` gets you output

```
 HELLO HELLO HELLO
```

Kinda useless since the output already goes where you'd want, but another example with the same HELLO.txt is `cat < HELLO.txt >&1` explicitly directing `cat`'s output to STDOUT.

More usefully, you sometimes find file descriptor 2's output (STDERR) being redirected with commands like

`grep somepattern /path/to/a_bunch_of_files/* 2>&1 >> alloutput.txt`

The `2>&1` stream directs errors to standard output.  Then all standard output is streamed to alloutput.txt. This would put error output in the file with standard output.